# How to read and push to an SQL database using pandas a file that is constantly getting data

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, continuous

I have a CSV file that is constantly getting new data chugged in (new rows appended at the end) by another program.

My goal is to read this file in python and push the incoming data on-line in a SQL database. I do not want to wait (or rather I cannot afford) that the file is finished before pushing the data. Once the file is open, the program should constantly wait for new lines to be pushed on the DB.

Pandas embeds a very useful method [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) that I am currently using to push the data on the database, which is why I'd love to keep using pandas.

Pandas' [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method accepts a *chunk_size* argument that I tried to use. The behavior is interesting, however the file is **not** reloaded each time a chunk is queried, hence not solving my problem. In this example

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', chunksize=1)
time.sleep(10)
df.get_chunk(5)
```

if the data in the file is modified during the sleep, it will not be catched when the chunks are queried.

Does anyone has an idea how could I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you would need to keep an open connection to pandas so it knows the last chunk it wrote to, alternatively you could use the `skiprows` argument  and read from that row everytime you read from the csv file. What happens if you move the csv after reading it?

Comment: @Manakin Once the csv file is loaded, windows prevent you from moving the file since it detects it's being opened in a program.
So you think it is required to just `read_csv()` continuously to access the latest data ? there's no way to kind of maintain the reading open to incoming data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general: just don't. If you're reading from a file that is open by another process, you cannot be sure that you're reading valid CSV (because the writing process could be halfway through the line).

If you insist though, there are a few ways to do it. The first would be using `watchdog`. This Python library makes it possible to "listen" for file changes. As soon as the file has changed (because the other process wrote new lines) you can call `pandas.read_csv` again.

Another way would be to periodically (e.g. every 10 seconds) check the contents of the file. This an example of what such a program would look like:

```py
import time
import pandas


def check_updates(n_rows_read: int) -> int:
    """ Check for updates in a file, starting from a specific row number.

    Args:
        n_rows_read (int): The number of rows in the file that are already read

    Returns:
        int: The total number of lines that are now processed in the file
    """

    # Read the file, starting from where we left off earlier
    df = pandas.read_csv("./test.csv", skiprows=n_rows_read)

    # TODO: Implement your logic here, and push to your SQL database
    # df.to_sql(...)

    return df.shape[0] + n_rows_read


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # In the begining we haven't read any lines yet
    n_rows_read = 0

    # Start an infinite loop
    while True:

        # Get updates, and keep track of how many rows of the file are processed
        n_rows_read = check_updates(n_rows_read)

        # Wait for a bit
        time.sleep(10)
```

NOTE: You will need to modify this code for your purposes

Comment: Thank you ! I did not know about the watchdog library.
I developed something similar than your code snippet. I was wondering if a better solution was possible using a library I did not know. Anyway thank you for you answer, it actually answers all my questions so I accepted this answer.